# Android simple game. ImageButton not clicking. Bitmap

Tags: java, android

I have created a custom ImageButton that will be used to change direction of objects in a simple game. The button is not responding when I click/touch it. 
I have tried setOnTouchListener and setOnClickListener but nothing happens.

CustomButton:

```
public class CustomButton extends ImageButton {

private Bitmap bitmap;

public CustomButton(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context);

    setClickable(true);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resource);
}

public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return bitmap;
}
```

GameView:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable { 

volatile boolean playing;
private Thread gameThread = null;
private CustomButton mLeftButton;
private Player player;
private Paint paint;
private Canvas canvas;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
public GameView(Context context, int screenX, int screenY) {
    super(context);

    mLeftButton = new CustomButton(context, R.drawable.boom);
    mLeftButton.setImageBitmap(mLeftButton.getBitmap());

    mLeftButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"It worked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    player = new Player(context, screenX, screenY);
    surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    paint = new Paint();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (playing) {
        update();
        draw();
        control();
    }
}

private void update() {
    player.update();
}

private void draw() {
    if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawBitmap(player.getBitmap(), player.getX(), player.getY(), paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mLeftButton.getBitmap(), 20, 20, paint);
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: where you add the button to view.

Comment: The button is "drawn as a bitmap"(?) in the draw-method.

Comment: you draw the bitmap in canvas not adding the button to view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create your button but not link it to the current layout.

In the draw method you simply draw it's image without adding its functionality to the `SurfaceView`, that way your button functionality is not used.

I'd suggest to create your base xml layout in a way where the button is over your surfaceview (with a `RelativeLayout` or a `FrameLayout` e.g.), then where you setup your `Activity` you'd setup up the onclicklistener for the button and wire it to the containing view.